# How to Use Acknowledgement in Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Use Case: I want to send Acknowledgement back from the consumer to the producer/topic, saying I have successfully consumed the message. For that, I have tried the below code(not complete one) but facing issue when triggering the endpoint.

Can anyone help me with how to get rid of the below issue and If the code to be modified please let me know I will change accordingly?

```
@GetMapping("/consumemessages")
@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.inputTopic.name}", groupId = "group_id")
@SendTo("responseTopic")
public String consume(Message<?> message) {
    log.info("Consumed Message"+message.getPayload());
    Acknowledgment acknowledgment = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
    if (acknowledgment != null) {
        System.out.println("Acknowledgment provided");
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        System.out.println("Ack----"+acknowledgment);
        System.out.println("Ack.ack----"+acknowledgment);
        return "Message Consumed";
    } else
        return "Message not published";
}


@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.inputTopic.name}", groupId = "group_id")
@SendTo("responseTopic")
public String consume(String message,Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    System.out.println("Consumed Message" + message);
    if (acknowledgment != null) {
        System.out.println("Acknowledgment provided");
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        System.out.println("Ack----" + acknowledgment);
        return "Message Consumed";
    } else
        return "Message not published";
}
```

I have tried with the above code samples, but I got the below error for **Message<?>** and **Acknowledgement** (Just replace the input package for messaging but the remaining error is same)

```
2020-09-18 14:47:48.355 ERROR 24216 --- [nio-7081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:208) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
```

Comment: It's not clear why you have `@GetMapping` and `@KafkaListener` on the same method; of course Spring MVC knows nothing about `Acknowledgement` (which is an interface) so it is failing to construct an instance.

Comment: Also you can't abuse `Acknowledgement` API sending it back to the producer. This callback is really about committing offset into consumer group. There is nothing producer-related in that API... Closing "as not clear what you are asking"...

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell  First code is not edited by mistake. Consider the second one, I am not using any mappers. Please help me like how can I send some confirmation back to the producer saying I have consumed the message. (Apart from committing the offsets)

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan Understood the way acknowledgment works. Thanks for the info. Can you help me on, how can I send some confirmation back to the producer saying I have consumed the message. (Apart from committing the offsets) ?

Comment: But your exception comes from the `web` module `>at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(` so something is not right.